# Composite vs Composition: which one is the correct word?

Tags: reference-request, terminology

So, I am a bit confused about the word I should use to refer to

$$f\circ g.$$

I have always used ''composition'' but I have seen some people (perhaps everyone who uses the term correctly) say composite.

I have added the reference-request topic in case you want to suggest a book explaining this sort of questions (I have no idea if such a book exists).

Comment: [Function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition): "is an operation that takes two functions f and g and produces a function..."

Comment: Are you using a noun?  If so "$f\circ g$ is the composition of $f$ with $g$" is standard.  Adjectives and verbs may use other forms.

Comment: Definition of *composition* : the act or process of composing. The *composite* is the result of the act of composing.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I think that's a good point. If I want to refer as $f\circ g$ I will have to say the ''composite'', meaning the composite function, won't I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Composition" is a noun: The composition of two surjective functions is surjective. "Composite" can act as an adjective, so it requires a noun to modify: The composite function is surjective as it results from composing two surjective functions. But it can also serve as a noun: Given two surjective function, their composite is surjective.

Comment: Can ''composite'' be used as a noun too by ignoring the word ''function''? That is, instead of saying $f\circ g$ is the composite function, just $f\circ g$ is the composite. PS: I apologised n advanced for if this question should be asked in the ELL site.

Comment: It seems "composite" can also serve as a noun. So, yes, "... is the composite" is fine.

Comment: Great!. I'm gonna accept your answer. Feel free to incorporate your comment to it.

Answer (score 2):

One may say that $f\circ g$ is a composite function, the word "composite" being an adjective, or that $f\circ g$ is a composition of functions.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $f \circ g$ is the function such that for all $x$, $(f \circ g)(x)=f(g(x))$. The RHS is the composition of $f$ and $g$. The LHS is the composite function: the result of meshing $f$ and $g$ into a single function. Performing the composite function $f \circ g$ on any given input  is the same as performing the functions $g$ and $f$ one after the other.

An analogy can be drawn with matrices. If $A$ and $B$ are two square matrices, then $A \times B$ is the single matrix that represents the linear transformation that results after applying $B$ and $A$ in succession.

Comment: I'd rather say $(f\circ g)(x)=g(f(x))$ ;)